# Windows API leads to different results based on name of unused variable?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, memory

Everything I know about .Net programming tells me that the behavior I see here is completely impossible. So can someone please explain what is going on here? Simple code:

```
Structure WKSTA_USER_INFO_1
    Dim wkui1_username As Integer
    Dim wkui1_logon_domain As Integer
    Dim wkui1_logon_server As Integer
    Dim wkui1_oth_domains As Integer
End Structure

Declare Function NetWkstaUserGetInfo Lib "Netapi32" (ByVal reserved As Integer, ByVal level As Integer, ByRef lpBuffer As Integer) As Integer
Declare Sub lstrcpyW Lib "kernel32" (ByRef dest As Byte, ByVal src As Integer)
Declare Sub RtlMoveMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByRef dest As WKSTA_USER_INFO_1, ByRef src As Integer, ByVal Size As Integer)
Declare Function NetApiBufferFree Lib "Netapi32" (ByVal Buffer As Integer) As Integer

Function GetDomain() As String
    Dim ret As Integer
    Dim wk1 As WKSTA_USER_INFO_1
    Dim pwk1 As Integer

    Dim test As String = ""

    ret = NetWkstaUserGetInfo(Nothing, 1, pwk1)
    RtlMoveMemory(wk1, pwk1, Len(wk1))

    ret = NetApiBufferFree(pwk1)

    Return "test"
End Function
```

When I put a break point in here, I see that after RtlMoveMemory, my wk1 contains a pointer to a username, and all the others are 0. This is consistant. Now, if I change `Dim test As String = ""` to `Dim login As String = ""` and run it again, wk1 contains pointers to both username and logon_domain.

If I change it to `Dim login As String`, it contains a pointer to only the username. Depending on what I change that (completely unused) variable name to, I get a different result. How is this possible?

I have always been under the impression that it cannot possibly matter what you choose to name your variable. And that declaring a variable, and then never using it, cannot possible be different from not having a variable there at all.

I've tried this on 2 computers, with consistant results (one on .Net 3.5 and one on 4.0). When I tried converting it to C#, however, I was not able to reproduce it.

I am aware, by the way, that I can just use System.Environment to get what I need about the current user information; this was old VB6 code that was automatically upgraded (and I've edited it a little to make it more trivial). I'm just trying to understand how this behavior is possible. Obviously I've spent many years assuming something about .Net that isn't quite true.

Comment: "declaring a variable, and then never using it, cannot possible be different from not having a variable there at all." There is a difference. There will be a small extra amount of memory used. In this case, having an extra string in the program will also increase memory because the string is still stored in the program. Forget all that if optimization is turned on. This isn't really relevant to the main question, but thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Can you provide a **complete** code sample that can reproduce it?

Comment: You are playing fast and loose with the pinvoke declarations.  This is certainly going to corrupt the stack if the code runs on a 64-bit operating system.  The side effects of which are pretty random and about what you describe.

Comment: Are you certain this is the compiler, not the debugger? What happens if you try logging `wk1` instead of using the debugger?

Comment: In all cases is the return value from NetWkstaUserGetInfo the success value?

Comment: @Kendall, the only part of the code that's missing to make it runnable is to call GetDomain() in Form_Load. (It's a Windows Application).

Comment: @hatchet, yes, always getting success

Comment: @Hans, this happens on both 32 bit and 64 bit OS.

Comment: I did not eliminate the possibility that these pinvoke declarations don't corrupt the stack in 32-bit mode.  It is merely more obvious that they absolutely do in 64-bit mode.  You'll need to get ahead by using proper declarations, you can find them at pinvoke.net or from the PInvoke Interop Assistant tool.

Comment: @Dour, you seem to be on to something. When I run the compiled exe, I get a value for the login_domain every time, no matter what the variable name is.

Comment: Your p/invoke for `RtlMoveMemory` is wrong. You are passing the address by address, which means that it copies the memory near `pwk1` instead of the memory pointed to by `pwk1`.

Comment: @RaymondChen, that's true! Changing the src to ByVal actually gets the code to work the same in VB.Net as it did in VB6. The auto-upgrader declared the functions incorrectly.

Comment: ALWAYS review auto generated code. It is guaranteed to get something wrong...

Comment: @Gendolkari, since you got it working, put your results into an answer and mark that answer as correct. Don't abandon your question as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution, with help from Raymond Chen:

The declaration for RtlMoveMemory should have src passed as ByVal, instead of as ByRef. Because the src that I'm passing is a pointer to a memory location, passing it ByRef caused it to pass the memory address of where my pointer was stored... in other words, the location of my variable declaration. Thus, having other variables or differently named variables around produced different results.

A note as to why it was being passed ByRef... in the original VB6 code, it didn't specify ByVal in the declaration, and ByRef is the default in VB6. So, the declaration itself was expecting ByRef. However, the call to the API specified that it was passing the variable ByVal. This is something that you cannot do in .Net; you have to pass it the same as the declaration is expecting. So the auto-upgrader added ByRef to the declaration, which does keep the declaration the same as VB6, but it ignored the ByVal in the call.